# UIViewController's prepare for segue method is not being called

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to pass data from a tableview cell into a tab view controller to be used by the tab view controller's corresponding views. However the overriden `func prepare` method below is not being called and the program goes to the tab view controller bypassing this method totally.

[Storyboard showing the views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csrux.png)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedCarIndex = self.savedCarsTableVC.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

    let destVC = segue.destination as! TabBarController
    destVC.selectedCar = savedCars[selectedCarIndex!]
}
```

I am expecting the `selectedCar` object to return data from the array however it's `nil`.

Comment: Hey @suleee, please copy-and-paste your code directly in your question (and format it using Markdown). You will get answers way faster man ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the selectedCarIndex in tableView didSelectRow method.  Also, make sure you want to be navigating to TabBarController and not some ViewController embedded in the TabBar.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "youridentifier", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedCarIndex = sender as! IndexPath

    let destVC = segue.destination as! TabBarController //Are you sure this is the correct ViewController to be casting to?
    destVC.selectedCar = savedCars[selectedCarIndex.row]
}
```

Comment: I think you might be right: he is casting to the wrong VC class and crashing the transition as a result :-(